# Grid View Autogenerated Column Data Type

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I am using asp.net grid view which has is populated dynamically that means it has auto generated columns at run time.
I just want to know db type of these columns whether a column is text , date or int type.

Please write back to me if any body has done this.

Regards
SYED

Answer (score 1):

When the database contents are re-bound to the grid view from the database, they are always Strings. Even if you have a numeric or date column, the data is rebound as a String.

This method isn't suitable for discovering the datatypes of your database table(s).